# Why is $f(x) = 4x + xz + 400$ not a trinomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Here's the function:

$$f(x) = 4x + xz + 400$$

I don't know why that's not a trinomial function. There are $3$ terms separated by a "$+$".

Comment: Well, you can combine the first two terms to write $f(x)=(4+z)x+400$ so I suppose this is just a "binomial function".  Since you did not write $f(x,z)$ I am assuming that $z$ is not a variable argument of $f$.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never heard the term "trinomial function". Can you provide a source for this terminology? ... Certainly, $4x+xz+400$ is itself a *trinomial*. Someone somewhere seems to be suggesting that considering the expression a function of $x$ *matters*, because it implies gathering terms by powers of $x$; but that's not actually how polynomial naming *works*. Go figure. ... Not-unrelatedly, we say that $4x+xz+400$ is a "quadratic" expression in the two variables $x$ and $z$; but it's only a "linear" function in either $x$ or $z$ individually. But that's a different issue.

Comment: In your source, what is the definition of "trinomial"? From Fibonacci to Viete, binomial and trinomial was used as grouping descriptor, for instance for number of terms under a root. Stevins introduced "multinomial" around 1590, Viete 5 years later "polynomial" for "many terms". Sometimes around 1800, "multinomial coefficients" were used, sometimes after 1900 "polynomial" got its modern content as algebraic expression in one or multiple variables. Afaik "binomial" and "trinomial" did not in general make this transition to a specialized meaning.

Answer (score 1):

A trinomial is a polynomial consisting of three terms or monomials. A monomial is a polynomial with just one term. The general form of a quadratic trinomial is

$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$

The function

$$f(x)=4x+xz+400=x(4+z)+400$$

is a polynomial with two terms (i.e. it is binomial) simply because $f(x)$ is a function which only depends on the variable $x$ (meaning that the dependent variable is defined to be $f(x)$ and not $f(x, z)$), hence the term $x(4+z)$ is a monomial.

However, if the function was defined as

$$f(x) = x^2 + 4x + 400$$

then $f$ would be a trinomial since both $x^2$ and $4x$ vary as $x$ changes.

Comment: Is the convention standard across all math books and Wikipedia? All the sources I have seen have labeled $ax^2+bx+c$ as a trinomial. While a zero degree polynomial would be a constant function, it appears that almost every source labels $ax^2+bx+c$ as a trinomial even though the last term is a constant function.

Comment: @KenDraco: *"When we use a specific number, it's not a trinomial."* ... Where did you get that idea? A "specific number" certainly counts as a term of a polynomial, and therefore it contributes to the naming convention. See, for instance, the ["trinomial" entry at MathIsFun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/trinomial.html).

Comment: @KenDraco: I guess that, as a student, you were not subjected to (way too many) textbook exercises in "factoring trinomials" such as $2x^2-5x-3$. (Congratulations?) In any case ... enjoy your hiatus!

Comment: @Axion004, I'm deleting my comments except this one. That was almost funny but looks like trolling here under your answer, and I'm logging out for a very, very long time again. Refer to Wikipedia please, if something was not clear in my comments when you are back here. Cheers.

Comment: @Blue, I guess something came over me today. I apologize. You are spot on. Somehow I turned a trinomial function into a binomial function because of the constant or because I don't know of what has come over me. Not myself today :) It's trivial but I feel bad not apologizing, especially seeing what great contributions you make to this site.

Answer (score 1):

$4x+xz+400$ *is* a trinomial, if you ask me. So would be $x+x+x$. "Trinomial" just means having three terms, and the way either thing is written, it has three terms.

It strikes me as incorrect to call a *function* "trinomial". It's a property of what you write, not what mathematical object it is. $x+x+x$ is a trinomial and $3x$ is a monomial. The function $f$ that triples its input is neither trinomial nor monomial, because those adjectives should apply to expressions written a certain way, not to functions.